# How to use std::any::Any without resorting to a 'static lifetime bound?

Tags: rust, polymorphism, traits, lifetime

I want to distinguish some generic containers at runtime using `std::any::Any`.

```
use std::any::Any;
use std::mem::MaybeUninit;

struct Container<T> {
    data: [MaybeUninit<T>; 42],
}

impl<T> Container<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let data = unsafe {
            MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init()
        };
        Container { data }
    }
}

struct Thingies {
    arr: Vec<Box<dyn Any>>,
}

impl Thingies {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Thingies { arr: Vec::new() }
    }
    pub fn add<T>(&mut self) {
        self.arr.push(Box::new(Container::<T>::new()));
    }
    pub fn lookup<T>(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Container<T>> {
        self.arr.iter_mut().find_map(|e| e.downcast_mut::<Container<T>>())
    }
}

fn test<T, U>() {
    let mut thingies = Thingies::new();
    thingies.add::<T>();
    let thingy = thingies.lookup::<T>();
    assert!(thingy.is_some());
    let thingy2 = thingies.lookup::<U>();
    assert!(thingy2.is_none());
}

fn main() {
    test::<i32, u32>();
}
```

This produces an error for each of my `add` and `lookup` methods like this:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:26:23
   |
26 |         self.arr.push(Box::new(Container::<T>::new()));
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
   |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...
   |
25 |     pub fn add<T: 'static>(&mut self) {
   |                 +++++++++
```

The issue seems to be that a trait object like `Box<dyn Trait>` is actually `Box<dyn Trait + 'static>` and the suggested fix would "solve" the issue by requiring `T: 'static` everywhere which I don't want.

So I tried [this tip](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/box-with-a-trait-object-requires-static-lifetime/35261/2) that suggests adding a lifetime that is different from `'static` but it wouldn't work. When declaring my struct like `struct Thingies<'a> { arr: Vec<Box<dyn Any + 'a>> }` I get the following error:

```
error[E0478]: lifetime bound not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:18:10
   |
18 |     arr: Vec<Box<dyn Any + 'a>>,
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: lifetime parameter instantiated with the lifetime `'a` as defined here
  --> src\main.rs:17:17
   |
17 | struct Thingies<'a> {
   |                 ^^
   = note: but lifetime parameter must outlive the static lifetime
```

`Any` seems to be special in this way because for other traits this strategy obviously works. While I'd like to understand why `Any` behaves this way and how to fix it, a solution not involving `Any` would also be appreciated if that's at all possible.

Comment: `Any` isn't special in the sense that the compiler treats it differently; it's literally just [defined to be `'static`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html). You can read [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-does-std-any-need-static-lifetime/84583/2) why this is necessary.

Comment: what would be the drawback of using `'static` for `T` and `U` in your use case?

Comment: @prog-fh My `Container` type should provide storage for something like `Box` so it would be nice to be able to store references, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `Any` without `'static`.

It is not "special", it just has an additional constraint. You can see the constraint in its [definition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html):

```
pub trait Any: 'static {
    ...
}
```

Adding `+ 'a` cannot remove that constraint. That works in the link since `dyn Trait` will *default* to `'static` in certain cases, but that is different than a *requirement* that it is `'static`.

You cannot use `Any` with any type that has non-static lifetimes; it allows you to downcast into concrete types but it cannot distinguish between `MyType<'a>` and `MyType<'b>` an thus is the reason for the constraint.

---

I think what you're looking for is not possible. If you want to store references, their lifetimes need to be tracked by the compiler to ensure they stay valid. Even if you associate a lifetime with your `Container` and require that types stored *outlive* that lifetime, that is not enough to guarantee that the type requested from `.lookup` would be valid. A type may be stored with a larger lifetime than what is looked-up, which is not ok for some types. See [variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html#variance). It may be theoretically ok if the type in question was covariant with respect to its associated lifetimes (and many types with lifetimes are covariant), but there is no way to constrain by variance so attempting that would be unsound. The other theoretical way it could work would be to constrain the type matches the lifetime *exactly*, but that syntax does not exist and likely never will.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. While it makes some sense to me, I am still wondering how to solve my underlying issue.

Comment: @purefanatic I've expanded my answer but I don't think what you want is possible, at least not generically.

Comment: That's a shame but thanks a lot for expanding on that!